# CORS preflight not happening consistently

Tags: cors

I'm seeing something weird with CORS, and I'm trying to confirm whether it's a bug or what...

Basically, I have a website, **www.example.com** which makes a number of POST requests to **log.example.com** to do logging. Since **log.example.com** is a different domain, CORS is in effect.

In most cases, I see a preflight OPTIONS request, followed by the POST request. However, on some occasions, I just see the POST, without a preceding OPTIONS - basically, something like this:

```
OPTIONS
POST
...intervening requests to www...
OPTIONS
POST
POST
...intervening requests to www...
POST
...intervening requests to www...
OPTIONS
POST
```

None of the OPTIONS requests return the Access-Control-Max-Age header (which they probably should, but that's a different matter), so the OPTIONS response shouldn't be cached by the browser. All the OPTIONS requests return a 200 and all the POSTS return a 202. Sometimes there are intervening requests, sometimes not. All the OPTIONS requests pass exactly the same headers and the responses return exactly the same combination of Access-Control-* response headers. The same goes for the POST requests.

I don't have (easy) access to the JS which is making the POST requests (I mean, I could probably *find* it, but it's obfuscated), but I don't think it should make any difference - I'm pretty sure they're just basic ole' XHR requests.

From the [fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org), if Access-Control-Max-Age is not passed, even if an entry is added to the preflight cache, it should be expelled immediately. Or could it be that because the second POST happens within one second of the first POST (which follows the OPTIONS request), there is an unexpired entry in the preflight cache?

Comment: Do you know if those OPTIONS-skipping requests are coming from different UAs/browser engines, or maybe you're seeing that pattern from only one UA? Because it sounds like it might just be a browser bug.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, I have only seen this on Chrome (51.0.2704.79 m) - I haven't tested on other browsers. I know the CORS test suites are pretty extensive, so I suspect a timing bug. From the fetch spec (5.8): "Entries must be removed [from the CORS preflight-cache] after the seconds specified in the max-age field have passed since storing the entry." It looks like entries might always get added to the cache (5.7.7.15 and 5.7.7.17) even though max-age is not passed. Even though they are nominally expelled from the cache 'immediately', they might be in there long enough for a second POST?

Comment: any luck with this ? even i am facing same issue , yesterday one of my rest api was working fine showing POST 200 , now its OPTIONS 200 with no response , I have added header with response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Answer (score 2):

Not all POST requests are preflighted (POST is a CORS-safelisted method). It depends on the headers that are included in the request. So if none of the headers are outside the CORS-safelisted request-header range, you won't get a preflight.

Comment: Hey Anne, I thought you might respond :) All POST requests are exactly the same, headers-wise, and they all include Content-Type: application/json, which isn't a CORS-safelisted request-header (although I think it probably should be :)... The weirdness is that some preflight and some don't, and I can't see any difference between them, except for the payload itself (which is only fractionally different).

Comment: Though the question is very old, it would be worth mentioning for others having the same issue.

I think that the OPTIONS (pre-flight) request might have been cached by your browser. This caching is enforced by the parameter: Access-Control-Max-Age (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age). 
Thus cache expiry can be the cause here.